# sfdx push error confusion

Tags: salesforcedx

Trying to push source to my scratch org, it fails without any error messages. So, I tried push --json and got this:

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "result": [
        {
            "error": "Unknown"
        }
    ],
    "name": "DeployFailed",
    "message": "Push failed.",
    "exitCode": 1,
    "commandName": "SourcePushCommand",
    "data": [
        {
            "error": "Unknown"
        }
    ],
    "stack": "DeployFailed: Push failed.    
                at MetadataRegistry.initializeMetadataTypeInfos.then.catch.e (/Users/patmcclellan/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.14.0-bd96f098e0/node_modules/salesforce-alm/dist/lib/source/sourceApiCommand.js:63:31)
                at tryCatcher (/Users/patmcclellan/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.14.0-bd96f098e0/node_modules/salesforce-alm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
                at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Users/patmcclellan/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.14.0-bd96f098e0/node_modules/salesforce-alm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:510:31)
                at Promise._settlePromise (/Users/patmcclellan/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.14.0-bd96f098e0/node_modules/salesforce-alm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:567:18)
                at Promise._settlePromise0 (/Users/patmcclellan/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.14.0-bd96f098e0/node_modules/salesforce-alm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:612:10)
                at Promise._settlePromises (/Users/patmcclellan/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.14.0-bd96f098e0/node_modules/salesforce-alm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:687:18)
                at Async._drainQueue (/Users/patmcclellan/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.14.0-bd96f098e0/node_modules/salesforce-alm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:16)
                at Async._drainQueues (/Users/patmcclellan/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.14.0-bd96f098e0/node_modules/salesforce-alm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:148:10)
                at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/Users/patmcclellan/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.14.0-bd96f098e0/node_modules/salesforce-alm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
                at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
                at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
                at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)",
    "warnings": []
}
```

Can anyone help me figure out what that means? It's referencing a bunch of files that aren't in my project or org, such as `timers.js`, `async.js`, `promise.js`, a directory called `bluebird`, and more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All mentioned files are the part of Salesforce CLI.

Do you have the latest version of SFDX CLI?
You can update it via terminal: `sfdx update`

It seems stuff you described is known issue. ([Issue](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/123), [Another Issue](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/1411))  If the update does not help, then try the following:

> Having the salesforcedx plugin installed overrides the code shipped by
>   the normal Salesforce CLI. If you still have the issue in version 7.13
>   and have the salesforcedx plugin installed you should either uninstall
>   that plugin or update to its latest version. [Source](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/123)

If nothing from above mentioned doesn't help - create an issue on official [Salesforce CLI Github](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues).

Comment: sfdx-cli: Updating CLI from 7.14.0-bd96f098e0 to 7.15.3-c7d407d236... done