# SFDX CLI - Unknown error when pushing code to Scratch

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, sfdx-plugin

I created a new scratch and trying to push the code I received an uknow error:

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "result": [
        {
            "error": "Unknown"
        }
    ],
    "name": "DeployFailed",
    "message": "Push failed.",
    "exitCode": 1,
    "commandName": "SourcePushCommand",
    "data": [
        {
            "error": "Unknown"
        }
    ],
    "stack": "DeployFailed: Push failed.\n    
    at MetadataRegistry.initializeMetadataTypeInfos.then.then.catch.e (/home/martinlarizzate/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.28.7-7bceba6f24/node_modules/salesforce-alm/dist/lib/source/sourceApiCommand.js:64:31)\n
    at tryCatcher (/home/martinlarizzate/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.28.7-7bceba6f24/node_modules/salesforce-alm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)\n    
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/martinlarizzate/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.28.7-7bceba6f24/node_modules/salesforce-alm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:517:31)\n    
    at Promise._settlePromise (/home/martinlarizzate/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.28.7-7bceba6f24/node_modules/salesforce-alm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:574:18)\n    
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/home/martinlarizzate/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.28.7-7bceba6f24/node_modules/salesforce-alm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:619:10)\n    
    at Promise._settlePromises (/home/martinlarizzate/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.28.7-7bceba6f24/node_modules/salesforce-alm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:695:18)\n    
    at _drainQueueStep (/home/martinlarizzate/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.28.7-7bceba6f24/node_modules/salesforce-alm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)\n    
    at _drainQueue (/home/martinlarizzate/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.28.7-7bceba6f24/node_modules/salesforce-alm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:131:9)\n    
    at Async._drainQueues (/home/martinlarizzate/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.28.7-7bceba6f24/node_modules/salesforce-alm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:147:5)\n    
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/home/martinlarizzate/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.28.7-7bceba6f24/node_modules/salesforce-alm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)\n    
    at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)\n    
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)\n    at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)",
    "warnings": []
}
```

As I read in other posts and google results, I asume that this error is related to the new CLI version because I updated it yesterday.

Im using Ubuntu and don't know how to rollback my CLI version.

Any Ideas?

EDIT:

This is my project-scratch-def.json config file

```
{
  "orgName": "Assured",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "features": ["Communities"],
  "settings": {
      "orgPreferenceSettings": {
          "networksEnabled": true,
          "s1DesktopEnabled": true
      }
  }
}
```

EDIT:
It looks as a CLI issue.
I viewed [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/270707/sfdx-push-error-confusion) but the problem started when I updated the CLI.

I went back to the version 6 but it stil happens

Comment: Could you add your scratch org definition file?

Comment: Hi @MartinLezer I just added it. Feel free to check again and thanks for your help.

Comment: It looks like a CLI issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I resolved this issue uninstalling the last version (7) and moving back to de previous one (6).

In my case the npm uninstal cmd did not work because I installed it manually so i removed the whole package folders:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/sfdx
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/sfdx
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/sfdx
sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/sfdx ~/.config/sfdx ~/.cache/sfdx
sudo rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/sfdx
```

Finally installed the version i need

```
npm i -g sfdx-cli@6.56.0
```